# Sincronização de variável em múltiplas Threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Olá.

A minha dúvida é sobre como usar o bloco ***synchronized***, a minha classe ***FileAdapter*** possui um método ***write*** que recebe o ***InputStream*** do resultado de uma conexão HTTP que estou usando para fazer o download de um arquivo, a cada kilobyte baixado e escrito no disco, ele chama o método ***downloaded*** da instância da classe ***DownloadReport*** que ele recebeu, para passar o que já foi baixado.


Em uma outra ***Thread***, que está imprimindo a saída para o usuário, ela chama o método ***updateProgress***, também da classe ***DownloadReport***, este método é responsável por atualizar uma barra de progresso que é exibida para o usuário no terminal.


O problema será se a classe ***FileAdapter*** tentar atualizar a quantidade de bytes baixados bem na hora que a ***Thread*** de saída tentar atualizar a barra de progresso, pois ambos os métodos editam o valor da variável ***intermediateDownloaded***, que funciona apenas como variável auxiliar, para segurar quantidade de bytes baixados desde a ultima atualização, para calcular a velocidade do download.


Se eu usar o bloco ***"synchronized (this)"***, dentro dos métodos ***downloaded*** e ***updateProgress***, ele vai bloquear toda a classe ***DownloadReport***, e a ***Thread*** de saída só vai poder atualizar a barra de progresso depois que a classe ***FileAdapter*** atualizar a quantidade de bytes baixados?


FileAdapter:

```
    public void write(InputStream content, DownloadReport downloadReport) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int read;

        while ((read = content.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloadReport.downloaded(read);
        }
    }
```

DownloadReport:

```
    public void downloaded(int bytes) {
        intermediateDownloaded += bytes;
        downloaded += bytes;
    }

    public void updateProgress() {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = UnitHelper.sizeRound(((now - lastTimeUpdate) / 1000.0), 2);

        if (delta >= 1) {
            unitAdapter.convertSpeed(intermediateDownloaded, delta);

            intermediateDownloaded = 0;
            lastTimeUpdate = now;
        }

        progressBar.updateProgress(unitAdapter.finalSize,
                unitAdapter.recalculate(downloaded), unitAdapter.unity);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha se isso te ajuda:

```java
Thread execucao = new Thread(() -> {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            processo.executar(quantum);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread Interrompida!");
        }
        notify();
    }
});
execucao.start();
synchronized (execucao) {
    execucao.wait();
}
```

Não sei mexer muito bem com threads, mas foi dessa forma que resolvi meu problema.